# C# Input string was not in a correct format int32

Tags: c#

I am having problems with formats and converting.

I have tried all workarounds and nothing.

**Code snippet where I think the error is**

```
label_Map.Text = message.Substring(21, 3);
label_Sys.Text = message.Substring(15, 3);
label_Dia.Text = message.Substring(18, 3);
label_Pulse.Text = message.Substring(26, 3);

SaveData(
    Int32.Parse(message.Substring(15, 3)),
    Int32.Parse(message.Substring(18, 3)),
    Int32.Parse(message.Substring(26, 3)));
```

**Example input string**

```
S1;A0;C03;M00;P120080100;R075;T0005;;D2
```

**End of errorcode**

```
InnerException: System.FormatException    
Message=Input string was not in a correct format.   
Source=mscorlib   
StackTrace:  
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number,  NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)  
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)  
at NIBP2PC.Form1.display(String message) in C:\Users\bazinga\Desktop\spiediena_merisana\NIBP2PC_c#\NIBP2PC\Form1.cs:line 427
```

Comment: Well, you've got lots of Substring calls. Have you looked at what those calls are returning?

Comment: might i suggest a regular expression?

Comment: That's a pretty bad way to get (what I assume) are the numbers out of that string. Try something a little more dynamic like string.split, or even better, Regex. Pretty obvious that you're trying to parse something that has a letter in it. Do some basic debugging.

Comment: This looks like a job for `var pieces = message.Split(';');` then simply removing the first character.

Comment: Doing a quick test, the indexes/lengths seem correct. Do you have any leading whitespace/newline characters? EDIT: Or maybe some culture-specific or special characters that we aren't seeing?

Comment: If the count of ;-separated items in S1;A0;C03;M00;P120080100;R075;T0005;;D2 is fix, you could use an explode/split function to get an array of the contents: string[] splittedStringArray = sourceString.Split(";"); - and then you can call your data by indexes. It would be easier than substringing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have more success trying to parse out the string for what you want.

```
public class InputCapture
{
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class InputParser
{
    const string pattern = @"(\w)(\d+)";
    private static readonly Regex Regex = new Regex(pattern);

    public IEnumerable<InputCapture> Parse(string input)
    {
        var inputs = input.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var parsedInputs = inputs.Where(i => Regex.IsMatch(i))
                             .Select(i => Regex.Match(i))
                             .Select(r =>
                                new InputCapture
                                    {
                                        Attribute = r.Groups[1].Value,
                                        Value = int.Parse(r.Groups[2].Value)
                                    });

        return parsedInputs;
    }
}
```

[image: Parsed results]

Answer (score 1):

Use the Split method with ';' as delimiter.. Then for each string do a loop in the chars to check if is digit (Char.IsDigit()). If is digit return false then exit loop(you know that it is not a number). Less code could be archived with a try{}catch{} statement. Inside try use converter to convert string to int. If it fails then In tha catch you know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Your substring is probably returning things like "P12" or "00;" which can't be parsed. Therefore the error message is correct (or rather, it's telling you what the problem really is). You're not going to get any data until you fix what strings you're sending in, but a better way to do this is to use "TryParse"

```
int myInt;
if (!Int32.TryParse(myString, out myInt)) throw new Exception() //or something more reasonable
```

Comment: `"S1;A0;C03;M00;P120080100;R075;T0005;;D2".Substring(15, 3)` returns "120" for me, not "P12". Am I missing something?

Comment: No you're right, I just counted it by hand the first time. The error message means he's picking up non-numeric characters though, so one of the substrings must be wrong, or we aren't seeing all the code.

Comment: If you're just going to throw an exception, `TryParse` offers no benefit over `Parse`.

Comment: You can handle the situation any way you want. I don't know how he wants to handle it, so I put something obvious in the example. Didn't you see the comment on that line?